# How can a socket be both connected and closed?

Tags: java, sockets

I'm using a Java socket client. In a case where the server is still connected to my client but it does not send a response to my message - I eventually get a read time out exception.

In that case I want to test to see if I should reconnect my socket or just keep it an re-use it.

I use this condition:

```
if (!socket.isConnected() || socket.isClosed() || !socket.isBound()) {
    try {
        socket.close();
    } catch (IOException e1) {
    }
    // Wait on a new connection
    socket = connectSocket(.....);
}
```

But I always seem to reconnect. When I log the values of the Boolean properties I see this:

connected: true closed: true bound: true

How can it be connected and closed?

TIA

Comment: Method calls are not atomic... perhaps another thread is closing the socket between the `isConnected()` and `isClosed()` calls?  Perhaps synchronize on the socket object first?

Comment: That's easy to test if you just reverse the order of the checks for `isConnected()` and `isClosed()`.

Answer (score 85, accepted):

[This thread](http://www.javakb.com/Uwe/Forum.aspx/java-programmer/7473/Socket-isConnected-isClosed) has some useful discussions on this topic. It turns out that [`Socket.isConnected`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/net/Socket.html#isConnected%28%29) returns true if it has (ever) been successfully connected.

From the above thread:

> When you use `Socket()`, which you seem to have overlooked,
>   `Socket.isConnected()` tells you whether `Socket.connect()` has been called
>   or not. Similarly for `isClosed()` and `close()`.
>
> Confusion over these methods results from confusing the state of the
>   *socket*, which is under the control of the application, with the state
>   of the overall *connection*, which is under the control of the protocol.
>   `isConnected()` and `isClosed()` tell what you have done to the socket.
>   There are no APIs other than read and write for determining the state of
>   the connection.

The docs says:

> *Returns true if the socket successfuly connected to a server*

and not as one perhaps would expect "*returns true if the socket is connected to a server*".

The behavior can be confirmed by looking at the source of Socket:

```
public boolean isConnected() {
    // Before 1.3 Sockets were always connected during creation
    return connected || oldImpl;
}
```

You could also run this little test snippet:

```
Socket s = new Socket();

System.out.println("isConnected: " + s.isConnected() +
                  " isBound: "     + s.isBound() +
                  " isClosed: "    + s.isClosed());

s.connect(new InetSocketAddress("google.com", 80));

System.out.println("isConnected: " + s.isConnected() +
                   " isBound: "    + s.isBound() +
                   " isClosed: "   + s.isClosed());

s.close();

System.out.println("isConnected: " + s.isConnected() +
                   " isBound: "    + s.isBound() +
                   " isClosed: "   + s.isClosed());
```

Which prints:

```
isConnected: false isBound: false isClosed: false
isConnected: true isBound: true isClosed: false
isConnected: true isBound: true isClosed: true
```

I must say that the documentation is quite unclear on this point, and that the method-name is a bit misleading.

Comment: Broken link, but from the quotations it appears to have been lifted holus-bolus from answers either here or at the Sun/Oracle Java Forums, many of them by me.

Comment: Nice answer. I had also confusion for isConnected.