# Difference between isConnected and isClosed

Tags: java, sockets

I would have assumed that calling `isConnected()` on a socket would tell me whether if is connected to the other side or not.

> Returns: true if the socket successfuly connected to a server

but after checking and then calling `flush()` on the socket I get

> java.net.SocketException: Broken pipe

How is `isConnected` different than `isClosed`, and what is the real behavior of each?

How do I tell if the other side if officially closed without writing anything to the streams, or creating new connections? Is there even a way?

Comment: These may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3701073/how-can-a-socket-be-both-connected-and-closed, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/151590/java-how-to-detect-a-remote-side-socket-close, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10240694/java-socket-api-how-to-tell-if-a-socket-has-been-closed

Comment: Same question as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3701073/how-can-a-socket-be-both-connected-and-closed

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> I would have assumed that calling `isConnected()` on a socket would tell me whether if is connected to the other side or not.

Wrong. It tells you whether *you* ever connected this Socket. It doesn't tell you about the state of the connection.

> Returns: true if the socket successfuly connected to a server

Note that it doesn't say *'is currently connected'* to a server.

> How is `isConnected` different than `isClosed,` and what is the real behavior of each?

The real behaviour of both is that they tell you what *you* have done to the *socket,* not what the state of the connection is.

> How do I tell if the other side if officially closed without writing anything to the streams, or creating new connections? Is there even a way?

No there isn't. If the peer closed normally, a read will return an EOS indication (`read()` returns -1, `readLine()` retuns null, `readXXX()` for any other XXX throws `EOFException`). A write will throw an `IOException` 'connect reset' or 'broken pipe' depending on your platform. TCP doesn't support anything in the nature of a 'dial tone', so absent a pending write there is no current connection status to enquire on.