# In Android how do I disconnect a socket?

Tags: android, sockets, disconnect

So I've got a socket that is connected to an outside web address and when it gets a certain message it's supposed to disconnect. I tried calling `socket.close()` but `socket.isConnected()` is still true. No luck searching for an answer

Answer (score 5):

`isConnected()` only tells you if you made a successful connection to a socket. `isClosed()` tells you if you called `close()`.

Check out this guys response https://stackoverflow.com/a/3701249/2453771

Comment: Ok so the next question is does calling close kill the connection? And if not what will?

Comment: Calling `close()` closes your side of the socket. The server isn't notified that you closed the socket though.

Answer (score 0):

> " When you use Socket(), which you seem to have overlooked,
>   Socket.isConnected() tells you whether Socket.connect() has been
>   called or not. Similarly for isClosed() and close().
>
> Confusion over these methods results from confusing the state of the
>   socket, which is under the control of the application, with the state
>   of the overall connection, which is under the control of the protocol.
>   isConnected() and isClosed() tell what you have done to the socket.
>   There are no APIs other than read and write for determining the state
>   of the connection."

[Oracle documantion](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/net/Socket.html#isConnected%28%29) < in here it's well explained that once you call `.close()` the connection is closed and you can check by `isClosed()`.

**.close()** :

> Closes this socket.
>
> Any thread currently blocked in an I/O operation upon this socket will
>   throw a SocketException.
>
> Once a socket has been closed, it is not available for further
>   networking use (i.e. can't be reconnected or rebound). A new socket
>   needs to be created.

Answer (score 0):

`isConnected()` and `isClosed()` tell you the current state of your socket *(in your side)*. 
`isConnected()` tells you whether ***you*** have connected this socket and `isClosed()` tells you whether ***you*** have closed this socket. Until you have, it returns false.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, right. It surely seems `socket.close()` and `socket.isConnected()` are independent from each other. I wish method naming was not as confusing.

From official [Android SDK](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/Socket#isConnected()):

> `public boolean isConnected()`
> Returns the connection state of the socket.
>
> **Note**: Closing a socket doesn't clear its connection state, which means
> this method will return true for a closed socket

P.S. more intuitively it should be called `wasConnected()`

Answer (score -1):

http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/Socket.html#close()

Do a checksum on the data returned, make sure you get the correct value.  If so and you called close and try-catch everything, it should be fine.

You could watch in a debugger and make sure nothing is leaking.

Answer (score -2):

try

```
socket.isClosed()
```

Returns a boolian, whether this socket is closed.
Refer
[Sockets](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/Socket.html)